# React Native : condition not working - unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am making a date calculator, and one of my conditions does not work:

```
{(parseInt(this.state.monthInit, 10) > 9 ?
    <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Stuff happens</Text> : 
    <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Different stuff happens</Text> }
```

Returns an error

> Unexpected token 167:69

which is right before the last bracket.

monthInit comes from:

```
<TextInput
    style={{height: 35, width: 30, textAlign: 'center'}}
    keyboardType = 'numeric'
    onChangeText={(monthInit) => this.setState({monthInit})}
    value={this.state.monthInit}
    placeholder="MM"
    maxLength = {2}
/>
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a closing `)`?

Comment: Well that'll teach me to rush debugging, i guess i have so much troubles with react-native i even forget good habits! ... Thanks for the help anyway man :)

Comment: voting to close as simple typo.